# python request.get returns '-' instead of data I need

Tags: python-requests

I have a very simple python script to get the air quality index from a website:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('http://aqicn.org/city/italy/lombardia/mantova-s.agnese/m/')
print(page.content)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

aqi = tree.xpath('//*[@id="xatzcaqv"]//text()')
print 'Aqi: ', aqi
```

When I inspect the element in google chrome, I get:

```
<div style="font-size: 42px; color: rgb(31, 18, 6);" id="xatzcaqv">149</div>
```

But the output of "print(page.content)" gives me:

```
<div style='font-size:42    px;' id='xatzcaqv'>-</div>
```

Why is request.get returning >-<, not the value >149< (the air quality)?

Comment: The page uses javascript to dynamically populate the text, replacing `-` with the actual value.

Comment: Is there a way to get the text with request.get?

Comment: you'll have to study the page and determine where the data comes from.  the browser debugger can help you better understand how the page works.

Comment: Use the API instead of trying to scrape the website's human-oriented presentation pages.  Start at http://aqicn.org/api/